# Study derivability in different directions given a point

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I must study the derivability in different directions at point $\overline A$ of $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy-x}{x^2+{(y-1)}^2}&\wedge&(x,y)\neq (0,1)\\0&\wedge&(x,y)=(0,1)
\end{cases},\qquad\overline A=(0,1).$$

I did the incremental quotient by definition for a generic versor $\hat r=(u,v)$:

$$\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{f((0,1)+h(u,v))-f(0,1)}{h}}=
\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{f(hu,1+hv)-0}{h}}=
\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{\frac{hu(1+hv)-hu}{{(hu)}^2+{(hv)}^2}}{h}}=
\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{hu(1+hv-1)}{h^2\underbrace{\left(u^2+v^2\right)}_{=\; 1}}\cdot\dfrac 1h}=
\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{huv}{h^2}}=
\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{uv}h}$$

... but I don't know how to proceed. Is my statement correct? If so, how do I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the formula for the directional derivative in terms of the partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, it is $f'\left(\vec{x_0};(1,0)\right)=f'_x\left(\vec{x_0}\right)$ and $f'\left(\vec{x_0};(0,1)\right)=f'_y\left(\vec{x_0}\right)$. But in this exercise they ask for any address, not for the canonical, right?

Comment: That's why I decided to do it by the most "general" definition (i.e. the formal one).

Comment: No that's not what I'm asking.  There's a simple formula that allows you to compute the directional derivative in any direction once you know the partial derivatives, so the best approach is to compute the partial derivatives first.  Do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: @saulspatz Oh I don't think so... Once I find the partial derivatives, what should I do?

Comment: I dont see any mistake in your calculations. Now observe that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{uv}h$ doesnt exists when $uv\neq 0$.

Comment: Look at the formula in the blue box on the second page of [these class notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mradclif/teaching/Math10C/LectureNotes/directional_derivatives.pdf)

Comment: ¡Hola @Masacroso! Nice to see you, thank you! I'm calm about that :).

Comment: @Masacroso I can't see why did you said the aggregate you made a while ago. If $uv=0$ then $\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{uv}{h}}=\frac 00$. I think it should be $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{uv}h$ doesn't exists when $uv=0$, right?

Comment: @saulspatz I have not seen that expression yet :(.

Comment: observe that $h\in\Bbb R$ and $h\neq 0$ in the limit (check the definition of functional limit), then you have $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac0h=0$. And $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac1h=+\infty\neq\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac1h=-\infty$

Comment: Ahhh that's true, $h$ cannot be $0$. So $f$ is derivable iff $(1,0),\;(-1,0),\;(0,1),\;(0,-1)$ whose derivative is $0$?

Comment: Then just do it the way way you started out.  Perhaps you haven't learned the formula yet.  The formula I'm thing of is that if $\vec u$ is a unit vector $(a,b)$ then $D_{\vec u}f = af_x+bf_y$

Comment: $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,1)$ by the previous comments. Im not sure if it is also non-differentiable at the other points you said.

Comment: @Masacroso The answer says "it is only derivable with result $0$ according to $(0,1), \; (0, -1), \; (1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$".

Comment: @saulspatz I understand what you say, but I should solve it without using formulas that I have not seen yet (although I would love to apply them). If the only way is that I will understand and apply.

Comment: @manooooh I dont know what the answer means but $f$ is neither continuous at $(0,1)$, so it cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: @Masacroso Ya I agree with you, but I think the answer speaks of directions, not of points (which is only evaluated in one, $\overline A$). Let's call Luis.... :P

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question. We have $$\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{uv}{h}}.$$ If we pick $a=0\;\vee\;b=0$ then the quotient is $0$ before calculating the limit, so in those four cases, $ (0,1), (0,-1), (1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ exists the limit and it's $0$.

Hence for $a$ and $b$ not null does not exist, for $a$ or $b$ null yes and it is $0$.